# MSSQL Проблема с уникальностью

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

Есть хранимая процедура, которая должна выполнять огромный запрос. Проблема в том, что этот запрос выводит
большое кол-во одинаковых данных(около 4000 позиций). Оставлю ссылку на код запроса.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iz5dhp_jAbfcFBXRdCftpylSi6ApKtaD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ну это всё отлично... а вопрос-то какой? если тупо избавиться от дубликатов - то DISTINCT.

Comment: Проблема в том что с DISTINCT, что без - результат один и тот же. Повторяющиеся строки не исчезают.

Comment: Ваш вопрос о проблеме с sql-запросом. Тогда почему в нём нет главного: метки `sql`. Зато вы зачем-то влепили метку `asp.net`. Исправьте.

Comment: *что с DISTINCT, что без - результат один и тот же. Повторяющиеся строки не исчезают.* Значит, они **НЕ** повторяющиеся. Хоть в одном поле, да различаются. Ибо чудес - не бывает.